# Why does eventlet/socketio not work when the server is run from a function?

Tags: python, sockets, python-socketio

The code below works as expected and runs without problem:

```
import socketio
import eventlet

port = 5000
sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={})

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connect')

eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', port)), app) # Note this line
```

However, as soon as the final line is wrapped in a function, an error occurs

```
import socketio
import eventlet

port = 5000
sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={})

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connect')

def run():
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen('', port), app) # Note this line

run()
```

This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thatcoolcoder/coding/micro-chat/tester3.py", line 16, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/thatcoolcoder/coding/micro-chat/tester3.py", line 14, in run
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen('', port), app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 49, in listen
    sock = socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 136, in __init__
    fd = _original_socket(family, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

How can I prevent this? I'm building a small chat app and to keep things clean, I need to create and run the server from within a function (specifically a class method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The issue is in this line:**

```
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen('', port), app)
```

**This line should be:**

```
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', port)), app)
```

**Updated Code:**

```
import socketio
import eventlet

port = 5000
sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={})

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connect')


def run():
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', port)), app) # Note this line

run()
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

The `eventlet.listen()` is a `param` of `eventlet.wsgi.server()`, and the `eventlet.listen()` means listen which address and port.

The `('', 8000)` combine the address and port. If we do not set the first param, it will be default 0.0.0.0.

If we set the `localhost` it will be look back address `127.0.0.1` and we also can set a IP address of our computer.

Comment: Another silly mistake by me... I'm not sure how this discrepancy came about - I started with the same code and pasted it into two files. I'll award the bounty when the timeout ends.